# my mule application for active mq is not working. Getting error like jar is missing

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am new to mule and trying to create mule flow with ActiveMQ. I have added all the related components and configured JMS component also. all seems fine but when I am running the application it is showing required jar is missing.

any help will be useful....thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing here to add the external jar for the acitveMQ.
Try adding activemq-all-5.15.0.jar or latest one in mule using add external jar.

I think that will work out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help...the problem got solved..:-)